# Join/merge two dataframes in R by columns with list entries

Tags: r, join, merge, data.table, dplyr

When working with dataframes, it can sometimes be helpful to store entries of `list` type in a column. I would like to join two dataframes by columns of that type. Here's an example of two such dataframes

```
dfm1 <- structure(list(val1 = 1:5, id = list(c(0.4, 0.5), c(0.4, 0.5), c(0.1, 0.5), 0.4, 0.4)), .Names = c("val1", "id"), row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = "data.frame")

dfm2 <- structure(list(val2 = 7:9, id = list(c(0.4, 0.5), c(0.1, 0.5), 0.4)), .Names = c("val2", "id"), row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = "data.frame")
```

I'd like to merge/join them by their columns named `id`, which contain `list` entries. Each `list` contains a single `vector` in this case (but it could contain a model object or really anything because lists are so flexible). For example,

```
> dfm2$id[1]
[[1]]
[1] 0.4 0.5
> class(dfm2$id[1][[1]])
[1] "numeric"
> is.vector(dfm2$id[1][[1]])
[1] TRUE
```

I can't think of how to join the `id` columns together so that `val1` from `dfm1` and `val2` from `dfm2` are in the same `data.frame`. When I attempt to use `dplyr` I get:

```
dplyr::left_join(dfm1, dfm2, by = "id")
```

> Error: cannot join on columns 'id' x 'id': Can't join on 'id' x 'id' because of incompatible types (list / list)

And I haven't had luck with the `data.table` package either:

```
 dt1 <- as.data.table(dfm1)
 dt2 <- as.data.table(dfm2)

 dt1[dt2, on = "id"]
```

> Error in forderv(x, by = rightcols) : 
>     First column being ordered is type 'list', not yet supported

Here is my desired output:

```
desired_dfm <- structure(list(val1 = 1:5, id = list(c(0.4, 0.5), c(0.4, 0.5), c(0.1, 0.5), 0.4, 0.4), val2 = c(7, 7, 8, 9, 9)), .Names = c("val1", "id", "val2"), row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = "data.frame")

> desired_dfm
  val1       id val2
1    1 0.4, 0.5    7
2    2 0.4, 0.5    7
3    3 0.1, 0.5    8
4    4      0.4    9
5    5      0.4    9
```

Thanks your help! If you have any suggestions along the lines of "You're being stupid by using a column of list entries - avoid that and do XXX instead", sure, that could be helpful, but I'm also looking for an answer to this problem as I've set it up :-)

**edit** I changed the entry in `dfm2$id[3]` from `c(0.1,0.2)` to `c(0.1,0.5)`.

**clarifying edit** Comments point out that it is possible to spread out this `id` variable into two columns and join on them instead. I agree that's possible, but this is a simple example, and there are more complicated situations in which that approach likely will not work.

Comment: Maybe `left_join(tidyr::unnest(dfm1), tidyr::unnest(dfm2))` ?

Comment: Care to show your desire output?

Comment: Use multiple columns instead of putting it all in a list.

Comment: @Abdou Yes; good idea. I edited it and it should show up soon.

Comment: @BarkleyBG, was the answer helpful in any way? Otherwise, could you please add a comment to indicate how it could be improved?

Answer (score 0):

The following is a very basic and uninspired way of getting to your desired output. It only works if your `lists` are `floats` or `integers` or `string` characters. But I thought it would help you get started:

#### Data

```
dfm1 <- structure(list(val1 = 1:5, id = list(c(0.4, 0.5), c(0.4, 0.5), c(0.1, 0.5), 0.4, 0.4)), .Names = c("val1", "id"), row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = "data.frame")

dfm2 <- structure(list(val2 = 7:9, id = list(c(0.4, 0.5), c(0.1, 0.5), 0.4)), .Names = c("val2", "id"), row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = "data.frame")
```

#### Process

```
library(magrittr)

#You need to create new columns of the same name for both of your datasets

dfm1$newcol <- do.call('rbind',lapply(dfm1$id,function(x) paste(x,sep="",collapse="")))

dfm2$newcol <- do.call('rbind',lapply(dfm2$id,function(x) paste(x,sep="",collapse="")))
```

The idea here is to create proxies for your `id` columns and use those proxies to merge the datasets. The proxies here are obtained through `concatenating` (or `pasting` together) the elements of each row in the `id` columns.

```
#Merge the datasets by 'newcol' and select the needed columns

merged_df <- merge(dfm1, dfm2, by = "newcol", sort=F) %>% subset(.,select=c("val1","id.x","val2"))


merged_df

 val1     id.x val2
    1 0.4, 0.5    7
    2 0.4, 0.5    7
    3 0.1, 0.5    8
    4      0.4    9
    5      0.4    9
```

If you want, you can rename the `id.x` column to `id` to reflect your original dataframe.

Also, according to the `str` function, the outputted dataframe still has `id.x` as of type `list`.

```
str(merged_df)
'data.frame':   4 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ val1: int  1 2 4 5
 $ id.x:List of 4
  ..$ : num  0.4 0.5
  ..$ : num  0.4 0.5
  ..$ : num 0.4
  ..$ : num 0.4
 $ val2: int  7 7 9 9
```

I hope this helps.